# How to clone a jquery inactive tabs

Tags: jquery, jquery-tabs

I am trying to clone inactive jquery tab from active tab (for eg I am on tab 1 and trying to clone tab2 which is inactive and append the clone value below tab 2 ) and append the same below it.

My function is working when I try to clone tab1 and append tab1 when I am on tab1 (active tab). But same function is not working when I try to clone tab2(inactive tab) from tab1.

Below is my code

```
<!-- tab1 -->
<div class="tab-pane active" id="tab_PersonalDetails">
<div class="row">  
    <div class="col-xs-4">
            <div class="form-group">
                    <form:label path="fname">First Name *</form:label>
                    <form:input class="form-control" path="fname" type="text" placeholder="First Name"/>
                    <span id="fnameError"/></span>
            </div>      
    </div>

    <div class="col-xs-4">
        <div class="form-group">
            <form:label path="isVehicle">Do you owe vehicle *</form:label>
             <form:select class="form-control"  path="isVehicle">
             <form:option value="">-- select --</form:option>
             <form:option value="Y">Yes</form:option>
             <form:option value="N">No</form:option>
             </form:select>
            <span id="isVehicleError"/></span>
        </div>  
    </div>
</div>
```

```
<!-- tab2 -->
<div class="tab-pane" id="tab_VehicleDetails">
<div class="row">                                        
    <div class="col-xs-4">
            <div class="form-group">
                <form:label path="slotNo">Parking Slot No *</form:label>
                <form:input class="form-control" path="slotNo" placeholder="Parking Slot No"/>
                <span id="slotNoError"/></span>
            </div>  
   </div>
</div>
```

```
<script>
    $( document ).ready(function() {
            $('#isVehicle').on('change', function() {
            // get selected value

            var status =  this.value;
            var TTi = 0;

            // if I try to clone tab1 from tab1 (active tab) then below code works but if i try to clone tab2 from tab1 to inactive tab2 it won't work

            // below code to clone tab_VehicleDetails (tab2)
            var flatoriginal = document.getElementById("tab_VehicleDetails"); 
            var TTclone = flatoriginal.cloneNode(true);
            flatoriginal.parentNode.appendChild(TTclone);
         });
    });

</script>
```

Comment: can you create a demo like http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/oto5hc4h/1/

Comment: I have create demo for clone to tab-1 one but how to clone tab-2 using same code [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/oto5hc4h/3/)

Comment: The cloned element has to be added as a new tab isn't it...

Comment: No I have to just append tab 2. Copy tab 2 and append the same below it in  tab 2 on change from tab 1

Comment: like http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/oto5hc4h/5/ ?

Comment: Yes this is what I want, but for some reason this make my tab 2 empty will check and see where am I making mistake in my code. I saw one more thing in your code `<div id="tabs"></div>` as a  parent div of all tabs.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you could do something like

```js
$(function() {
  $("#tabs").tabs();
  $('#testclone').on('change', function() {
    var value = $(this).val();

    var $ts = $('#' + value).find('.clone');
    var $el = $ts.first().clone();
    $el.insertAfter($ts.last())
  });
});
```

```html
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.0/jquery.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.10.4/themes/redmond/jquery-ui.css">
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.10.4/jquery-ui.js"></script>

<div id="tabs">
  <ul>
    <li><a href="#tabs-1">Nunc tincidunt</a></li>
    <li><a href="#tabs-2">Proin dolor</a></li>
    <li><a href="#tabs-3">Aenean lacinia</a></li>
  </ul>
  <div id="tabs-1">
    <div class="clone">
      <p>Proin elit arcu, rutrum commodo, vehicula tempus, commodo a, risus. Curabitur nec arcu. Donec sollicitudin mi sit amet mauris. Nam elementum quam ullamcorper ante. Etiam aliquet massa et lorem. Mauris dapibus lacus auctor risus. Aenean tempor ullamcorper leo. Vivamus sed magna quis ligula eleifend adipiscing. Duis orci. Aliquam sodales tortor vitae ipsum. Aliquam nulla. Duis aliquam molestie erat. Ut et mauris vel pede varius sollicitudin. Sed ut dolor nec orci tincidunt interdum. Phasellus ipsum. Nunc tristique tempus lectus.</p>
    </div>
    <select id="testclone">
      <option value=""></option> 
      <option value="tabs-1">tab-1</option> 
      <option value="tabs-2">tab-2</option> 
      <option value="tabs-3">tab-3</option> 
    </select>
  </div>
  <div id="tabs-2">
    <div class="clone">
      <p>Morbi tincidunt, dui sit amet facilisis feugiat, odio metus gravida ante, ut pharetra massa metus id nunc. Duis scelerisque molestie turpis. Sed fringilla, massa eget luctus malesuada, metus eros molestie lectus, ut tempus eros massa ut dolor. Aenean aliquet fringilla sem. Suspendisse sed ligula in ligula suscipit aliquam. Praesent in eros vestibulum mi adipiscing adipiscing. Morbi facilisis. Curabitur ornare consequat nunc. Aenean vel metus. Ut posuere viverra nulla. Aliquam erat volutpat. Pellentesque convallis. Maecenas feugiat, tellus pellentesque pretium posuere, felis lorem euismod felis, eu ornare leo nisi vel felis. Mauris consectetur tortor et purus.</p>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div id="tabs-3">
    <div class="clone">
      <p>Mauris eleifend est et turpis. Duis id erat. Suspendisse potenti. Aliquam vulputate, pede vel vehicula accumsan, mi neque rutrum erat, eu congue orci lorem eget lorem. Vestibulum non ante. Class aptent taciti sociosqu ad litora torquent per conubia nostra, per inceptos himenaeos. Fusce sodales. Quisque eu urna vel enim commodo pellentesque. Praesent eu risus hendrerit ligula tempus pretium. Curabitur lorem enim, pretium nec, feugiat nec, luctus a, lacus.</p>
      <p>Duis cursus. Maecenas ligula eros, blandit nec, pharetra at, semper at, magna. Nullam ac lacus. Nulla facilisi. Praesent viverra justo vitae neque. Praesent blandit adipiscing velit. Suspendisse potenti. Donec mattis, pede vel pharetra blandit, magna ligula faucibus eros, id euismod lacus dolor eget odio. Nam scelerisque. Donec non libero sed nulla mattis commodo. Ut sagittis. Donec nisi lectus, feugiat porttitor, tempor ac, tempor vitae, pede. Aenean vehicula velit eu tellus interdum rutrum. Maecenas commodo. Pellentesque nec elit. Fusce in lacus. Vivamus a libero vitae lectus hendrerit hendrerit.</p>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: It was by mistake I added #tab_VehicleDetail in post. I changed it but still not working. But when I clone tab1 its working but not working for tab2 clone.